# Pause function crashes game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

So I am making an endless runner game, and I have made a function that *should* pause the game when the event runs, yet when I try to play the game, it crashes/doesn't load. Does anyone know why? I also tried an if function instead of a while loop, but when I pressed the `P` key, nothing happened. Essentially, I want it to freeze everything if the `PP` Boolean is set to false.

If you want to test it, I have it here: https://aakhilv.js.org/endless-runner/

Here is my code (only the relevant bits):

```js
// Booleans
let UP = false;
let DOWN = false;
let HKD = true;
let PP = true;

// Controls
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (HKD && e.keyCode == 38) UP = true;
  HKD = false;
  if (e.keyCode == 40) DOWN = true;
};

document.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (!e.repeat && e.keyCode == 38) UP = false;
  if (e.keyCode == 40) DOWN = false;
};

document.onkeypress = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 80 && PP) PP = false;
  if (e.keyCode == 80 && !PP) PP = true;
};

// Frames
function update() {
  // Clear
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 512, 512);

  // Environment
  ctx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0);
  ctx.drawImage(fl, 0, 384);
  ctx.drawImage(fl, 128, 384);
  ctx.drawImage(fl, 256, 384);
  ctx.drawImage(fl, 384, 384);
  ctx.drawImage(cb, 10, 10);
  ctx.drawImage(c, 0.5, 0, c.width / 2, c.height / 2);
  ctx.font = "40px Font";
  ctx.textAlign = "left";
  ctx.textBaseline = "top";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#ae7640";
  ctx.fillText(0, 55, 15);


  // Enemies
  if (mx >= -128) {
    ctx.drawImage(m, mx -= speed, 256);
  } else if (mx <= 0) {
    mx = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1024 - 512) + 512);
  };

  if (bx >= -256) {
    ctx.drawImage(b, bx -= speed, 215);
  } else if (bx <= 0) {
    bx = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1536 - 512) + 512);
  };

  if (cx >= -384) {
    ctx.drawImage(c, cx -= speed, 280);
  } else if (cx <= 0) {
    cx = Math.floor(Math.random() * (4608 - 512) + 512);
  };

  while (Math.abs(mx - bx) < 192) {
    mx = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1024 - 512) + 512);
    bx = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1536 - 512) + 512);
  };

  // HKD
  if (y == 256) {
    HKD = true;
  };

  // UP
  if (UP) {
    if (y > 100) {
      ctx.drawImage(pl, 0, y -= speed);
    } else {
      UP = false;
    };
  } else if (!UP) {
    if (y < 256) {
      ctx.drawImage(pl, 0, y += speed);
    } else {
      ctx.drawImage(pl, 0, y);
    };
  };

  // DOWN
  if (DOWN) {
    pl.src = "./Assets/Duck.png";
  } else if (!DOWN) {
    pl.src = "./Assets/Idle.png";
  };
};

while (PP) {
  setInterval(update, 10);
};
```

Comment: Please add a [mre]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be here -

```
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 80 && PP) PP = false;
  if (e.keyCode == 80 && !PP) PP = true;
};
```

Initially PP = true

Now if user presses 'P'
1st if condition would be true and PP would be assigned false;

Now the 2nd condition would be checked, !PP would resolve to true, because of previous if code execution, so PP reverts back to true.

You might want to use if else above, i.e,

```
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 80 && PP) PP = false;
  else if (e.keyCode == 80 && !PP) PP = true;
};
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked fantastically!

Answer (score 1):

```
while (PP) {
  setInterval(update, 10);
};
```

The code above infinitely calls setInterval, which will create infinitely many intervals. Instead, you want to `setInterval` only once, and then check within `update` if `PP` is true and skip the function body if it's false.

```
function update() {
  if(PP){
    // Clear
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 512, 512);

    // Environment
    ctx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0);
    // ...
  }
};
setInterval(update, 10);
```

Other comments on the code: You should name your variables something understandable to others, and you don't need semicolons after the closing "}". Also, `if` is not a function.

Comment: Hmm... I tried that, yet when I press the `P` key, it still doesn't freeze the canvas, it just continues as normal. There's no errors in the console either.